# Filtrar con pattern rango de puertos

Tags: html, html5, regex

Me gustaría saber como se puede filtrar con pattern un rango de puertos tal que solo acepte o números o números con dos puntos en medio y ya puestos que no sobrepase 65535.

Ejemplo: **20** o **20:25**

Lo único que se me ha ocurrido ha sido este filtro **pattern="[0-9]{1,5}"** lo único que hace es limitar a números de no mas de cinco cifras

Comment: http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/ genera un regex a partir de un rango numérico.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para que permita introducir o un número o dos números separados por `:`, basta completar tu patrón `<puerto>` para que sea `<puerto>(:<puerto>)?`:():

```
pattern="[0-9]{1,5}(:[0-9]{1,5})?"
```

Para que no permita introducir números mayores de 65535, es más complicado, pero no imposible con un poco de ingenio:

```
pattern="([1-9][0-9]{0,3})|([1-5][0-9]{4})|(6[0-4][0-9]{3})|(65[0-4][0-9]{2})|(655[0-2][0-9])|(6553[0-5])">
```

Ahora tan sólo queda combinar ambas en `(<puerto>)(:(<puerto>))?`:

```
pattern="(([1-9][0-9]{0,3})|([1-5][0-9]{4})|(6[0-4][0-9]{3})|(65[0-4][0-9]{2})|(655[0-2][0-9])|(6553[0-5]))(:(([1-9][0-9]{0,3})|([1-5][0-9]{4})|(6[0-4][0-9]{3})|(65[0-4][0-9]{2})|(655[0-2][0-9])|(6553[0-5])))?">
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias!. 
He estado buscando por la web y la información que encuentro de patrones es bastante básica, alguna referencia?

Comment: Tienes una de las mejoras herramientas disponibles para trabajar con expresiones regulares en https://regex101.com/